# Retrofit2 response.body() returns c.f.a.r0@13b62af9

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit2

Retrofit2 returns c.f.a.r0@13b62af9 when I call response.body(), thus I cannot parse the content. Am I doing something wrong

public class ApiClient {

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "url-here";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

and here's my ApiInterface

public interface ApiInterface {

```
@GET("getNearbySpots.php")
Call<SpotResponse> getNearbySpots(@Query("lat") String lat, @Query("lng") String lng);

@GET("internetTime.php")
Call<InternetTimeResponse> getInternetTime();

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("addReservation.php")
Call<String> addReservation(@Field("hash") String hash, @Field("spotId") String spotId, @Field("spotName") String spotName, @Field("spotLocation") String spotLocation,
                            @Field("name") String name, @Field("email") String email, @Field("phone") String phone,
                            @Field("foodieCount") int foodieCount, @Field("timeSlot") String timeSlot, @Field("bookingDate") long bookingDate,
                            @Field("freeBooking") boolean freeBooking, @Field("cost") int cost, @Field("tipAmount") int tipAmount);

@GET("getReservationForHash.php")
Call<ReservationResponse> getReservationForHash(@Query("hash") String hash);

@GET("getReservationById.php")
Call<ReservationResponse> getReservationById(@Query("resId") int resId);

@POST("addUser.php")
Call<String> addUser();
```

}

**EDIT**

Here is where response.body() is called

```
private void fetchData(String lat, String lng){
    Call<SpotResponse> call = apiService.getNearbySpots(lat, lng);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<SpotResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<SpotResponse> call, @NonNull 
Response<SpotResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                ListA = new ArrayList<>();
                ListA = response.body().getSpotList();
                String dateToFormat = response.body().getTime();
                Log.e("MainActivity", "responseBody: " + response.body());
                restaurantUtils = new RestaurantUtils(dateToFormat);
```

Comment: what response.body() exactly??

Comment: @Sadegh I edited my question to include where response.body() is called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `toString()` method to SpotResponse class what you want showing in `Log.e("MainActivity", "responseBody: " + response.body());`

Answer (score 0):

try with this code instead of `Log.e("MainActivity", "responseBody: " + response.body());`

```
 for(int i = 0; i<ListA.size(); i++){

        Log.e("MainActivity", "lat "+ i + " : "+ ListA.get(i).lat); 
        Log.e("MainActivity", "lng "+ i + " : "+ ListA.get(i).lng);    
}
```

it prints all of lats and lngs . you can't print `response.body()` because type of that is SpotResponse class.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was having minifyEnabled true

Thank you for all your suggestions.